# Audio output on AMD HD 3450

Tags: hdmi, dvi, amd-radeon

I've just installed this graphics card under Windows 7 32 bit and I'm unable to find any reference to the onboard audio driver. AMD's [own website](http://www.amd.com/US/PRODUCTS/DESKTOP/GRAPHICS/ATI-RADEON-HD-3000/HD-3400/Pages/ati-radeon-hd-3400-overview.aspx) says that it should have 5.1 surround, and the card has an HDMI output which I would hope outputs both video and audio.

I'm currently running it off DVI to HDMI with a passive converter (was the only cable I had lying around and don't want to fork out for an HDMI if this works fine).

Does anyone here have any ideas on how to convince the card it has audio capabilities?

Edit: To respond to the questions by @afrazier, the catalyst interface says nothing about audio at all, and I've looked through all of the inf files (using the add new hardware wizard) and not found any audio drivers. No audio device shows up in the control panel, nor does a question marked "unknown item".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that I'd missed out an important piece of information from my original question. I have the AGP version of this card, which does not have support for sound.

Answer (score 1):

First off, did the latest Catalyst installer say anything about the HDMI audio driver? It should list it in the custom install.

It should also show up as an audio device in the appropriate control panel.

Next, you may need to use the hdmi port for audio to work. Even if you can use the dvi to hdmi adapter, it has to be the appropriate one for the card. ATI has changed the adapters over time. I know the 3000 series adapters were different from the 2000 series ones and not interchangeable, but I think the adapters for 4000 series cards also work.

Comment: I suspected that I'd have to use and HDMI cable for it to activate the audio part of the card but wanted to see if there were alternatives first. I've updated my question with some answers to what you've asked.